# Display text different to actual value when actual value is *

Tags: excel

That's basically it.

I have a `*` in some cells to represent "All" data, because I need it for some formulas later, but I want to use it in the titles so it would be nice if it could display "Total" but still maintain the `*` below.

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the cell should be showing "Total" (red arrow) while mantaining the vale as "*" (blue cirlce).

Tried a few tutorials but nothing seems to work, I'm not sure if it's because it's an asterisk or what.

Edit: the tutorial I mostly followed is [this one](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4264-excel-display-different-text-than-value.html), in my case instead of 1,2,3,4,etc I have * (aka the value) and I want to display "Total" instead.

Comment: can you demonstrate with a example or attach the file

Comment: @Ranga there's no good way to demonstrate it but I included the tutorial that explains what I want to do (except it's not working for me)

Comment: Show us some picture and what you are trying to achieve your question needs more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom number formats in Excel split into four categories:

1. Positive values
2. Negative values
3. Zero values
4. Text values

* is a text value so you want the fourth category and you get this by inserting semicolons before the required format to indicate that 1, 2 and 3 don't apply so you end up with:

```
;;;"Total"
```

[image]

where A2 and A4 actually contain an asterisk.

Comment: I can't believe this worked finally after looking for so long! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! It took me a while as well.

Comment: brilliant way, I was thinking a lot on how to do this

Answer (score -1):

You have cells that have contents X but you want Excel to say,  "no,  no.   I'm going to show you Y"?

Aside from sounding like a maintenance nightmare, I am not aware of a way to do that.

Comment: Basically... yes! Some coworkers before me have done it, also I linked a tutorial that shows how to do it, but I can't get it to work with an asterisk.